# What does the charset parameter of CreateFont exactly set?

Tags: winapi, internationalization, fonts, character-encoding, gdi

The code page on my Windows is set to ANSI (Latin1, Windows-1252).
I create a font with CreateFont and pass RUSSIAN_CHARSET in fdwCharSet

This is what I experience:

- Windows controls (like a Static for example) using this font ignore the font's character set: the string passed to SetWindowTextA is displayed with Latin characters
- After selecting this font on the DC, GDI text functions (Ext)TextOutA and DrawTextA use the character set of the font. Strings passed to them are displayed with cyrillic letters.

Why? When is the charset parameter of the font taken into account and when is it ignored? Can I force windows controls to use the font's character set?

Comment: Yes, use SetWindowTextW().  Russian text cannot be properly converted to an ansi string by SetWindowsTextA() when the code page is 1252.  It doesn't have any cyrillic characters.

Comment: I know using wide char is the correct way of doing it, but in my case it is hard to do (extremely big and fairly old system). I wonder why does font charset setting worka differently for GDI text functions and for controls drawn by Windows itself.

Comment: Looks like I should not use any xxxA api. Unicode is a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to convert the text to Unicode and call `SetWindowTextW()` instead of `SetWindowTextA()`.

Make sure the window's class is registered with `RegisterClassW()` and not `RegisterClassA()`.  This is what really determines if a window is Unicode.  You can use `IsWindowUnicode()` to verify that the window is really Unicode.

Make sure you pass unhandled messages to `DefWindowProcW()` and not `DefWindowProcA()`.

Or, if the window is a dialog, just make sure it is created with `CreateDialogW()` or `DialogBoxParamW()`.

Answer (score 0):

>Can I force windows controls to use the font's character set?

AFAIK no, you can't.

SetWindowTextA just converts the argument to Unicode, then calls SetWindowTextW: both windows kernel, shell, and GDI are unicode.

To convert the argument to Unicode, SetWindowTextA uses the setting from Window's regional options ("Language for non-Unicode programs").

Comment: It's not quite that simple.  SetWindowTextA converts to Unicode only if the window was created in Unicode mode rather than ANSI mode.  For ANSI windows, the conversion to Unicode appears to happen at WM_PAINT, at which point the information is lost.

Comment: I also admit seeing such call sequence there: ExtTextout -> GetCodePage -> GDIGetEntry -> NtGdiGetCharSet -> win32u.NtGdiPolyPatBlt

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening:

1. You call SetWindowText with something like `"\xC4\xEE\xE1\xF0\xEE\xE5 xF3\xF2\xF0\xEE"`.
2. You're compiled as an ANSI application rather than Unicode, so that maps to a call to SetWindowTextA.
3. SetWindowTextA sees that the window was created in ANSI mode, so it sets the string directly.  (If it had been a Unicode window, then it would converts the ANSI input string to Unicode and passes it onto SetWindowTextW.)
4. The ANSI window converts the ANSI string to Unicode so that it can display it.  But it doesn't know the string is in a different code page than the default one for the system.  It's this conversion that's changing everything back to Latin characters.  It assumes that the input string is in the process's default code page (Windows 1252 in your case).  So now you have a bunch of accented Latin characters instead of a string of Cyrillic ones.
5. The control tries to display this Unicode string using something like DrawTextW or TextOutW.
6. The lower level part of the system says, "Oh crap, this string is a bunch of Latin characters, but the user has chosen a Cyrillic font."  To solve the problem, it uses font linking (or font fallback, I get those terms confused) to effectively select a font compatible with 1252.
7. You see Latin gobbledygook instead of proper Russian.

I tried coming up with a minimal way to do what you need, but I failed.  My first idea was to do the conversion yourself and call SetWindowTextW directly:

```
void SetWindowTextRussian(HWND hwnd, char *pszCyrillic) {
    const int cchCyrillic = ::lstrlen(pszCyrillic);
    const int cchUnicode = 4 * cchCyrillic;  // worst case
    WCHAR *pszUnicode = new WCHAR[cchUnicode];

    // See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx
    const UINT CP_CYRILLIC = 1251;
    if (::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_CYRILLIC, 0, pszCyrillic, -1,
                              pszUnicode, cchUnicode) > 0) {
        ::SetWindowTextW(hwnd, pszUnicode);
    }

    delete [] pszUnicode;
}
```

But this doesn't work.  I suspect that since the window was created as an ANSI window, the Unicode string is converted back to ANSI (assuming the wrong code page again), and then you get question marks instead of Latin nonsense.

I think you're going to have to convert to a Unicode app, or only run with the default code page set to 1251.

**Update**:  If you control the creation of the window (e.g., you call CreateWindow directly rather than having a dialog box instantiate the controls), then you can probably make the above work by calling CreateWindowW directly and creating a Unicode window for the controls that matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.I tried the CreateWindowW solution and it does not help. Probably the conversion to unicode in SetWindowTextA works just like the one in WM_PAINT: it uses the current system wide code page. However, your SetWindowTextRussian is working OK for me. The solution will be something similar - still, I don't see the reason behind the different behavior of DrawTextA and SetWindowTextA.

Comment: **UPDATE**: OK, I see now that you suggest me to use CreateWindowW **and** SetWindowTextRussian at the same time. Actually, this is indeed what is working OK.

Comment: @Gabor Herman: I'm glad you got it working.  Sorry if I wasn't clear enough that I was suggesting to use both CreateWindowW and SetWindowTextRussian together.

Answer (score 0):

Consider hooking gdi32full.dll GetCodePage to select the code page that you need. CP_UTF8 for example. It has single pointer param, returns single DWORD (the code page) and stdcall calling convention.